# Hard Reload Webpage without Cache in Safari 14.0

Tags: safari, browser-cache

To enable clearing of cache and hard reloading in Safari for Mac, I was using `Shift+Command+R` button on the Safari Web Inspector.

But after I upgraded to Safari version 14, the `Shift+Command+R` button does not reload without cache. Instead, it pops out the Readers View.

Can someone tell how does one do hard reloading by clearing cache in Safari Version 14 specifically. This used to be a good tool for developers. Has this feature been retired by any chance?

I use OS Catalina 10.15.

Answer (score 4):

You can select, "Reload Page From Origin" from the "View" menu. You should be able to use `Command+Option+R`, but that seems to be buggy for me and actually pulls up the reading view frequently.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't see this option in my View menu option. Also checked preferences, where I didn't see a setting for this either.

Comment: Hold the Option  while in the view menu to see the option.  ⌥+⌘+R is the keystroke to load page from origin.